# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Selenium Java

Tags: java

Issue coming in Java selenium environment in eclipse, otherwise simple java program is running fine in eclipse but when I config Selenium Java Environment in eclipse shows me this error. How we can resolve?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW9ZF.png)

I am trying to resolve this issue for past 3-4 days.